# why it is clear:both but not clear:left in clearfix?

Tags: css, css-float, clearfix

"clear:both" is used in the famous class "clearfix", but I wonder if it is enough to use "clear:right"?
Since the element which :after created always location as the last element of the container,so I don't konw if a "clear:right" will cause any problem?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The direction of `clear` must match the direction of `float` of the floating elements that are being cleared. If you will only ever have right-floating elements, then there is nothing wrong in using `clear: right`, but if you have any left-floating elements then those elements will not be affected by this clearance.

A clearfix typically uses `clear: both` to account for either case.